# JPA createEntityManager causes Oracle 955 error

Tags: oracle, jpa, persistence, ora-00955

I have created a simple JAVA app to learn database connection.

I have table USR_BOOKS in Oracle 11g database. Using EclipseLink(JPA 2.0) Persistence libray.

Using "Create Entity From Database", I created a class in Java, and created JPA Controller class.

Everything seems to work fine except that I always get

```
    [EL Warning]: 2012-10-30 16:50:31.957--ServerSession(1278203495)--Exception 
       [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
    Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

    Error Code: 955
    Call: CREATE TABLE USR_BOOKS (ID NUMBER(19) NOT NULL, NAZOV VARCHAR2(255) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))
    Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE TABLE USR_BOOKS (ID NUMBER(19) NOT NULL, NAZOV VARCHAR2(255) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))")
```

I am not calling the CREATE TABLE query anywhere, but until I call function

```
   EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

the error is not there 
It looks like that the function createEntityManager() creates the SQL statement and sends it into database.

I tried deleting the table from database. Then the program creates the table USR_BOOKS in database - again, I am NOT accidentally calling any function that could cause it.

This is basically my code:

```
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JavaOracleDBPU2");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    UsrBooksJpaController booksController = new UsrBooksJpaController(emf);
    List<UsrBooks> usrBooksAll = booksController.findUsrBooksEntities();
    System.out.println(usrBooksAll);
```

the code works, even prints data from the table, just getting the error

Answer (score 1):

Possibly in persistence.xml [eclipselink.ddl-generation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DDL) property does have value `create-tables`. Try `none` instead:

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none"/>
```